# Laravel customize validate json error message structure

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to change the structure of the response to validate error messages rather than the errors themselves. The Laravel documentation on validate is extensive but unfortunately they only explain how to change specific error messages.

Ultimately what I'm trying to do is change it from this format
When I use this

```
  $attr = $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|unique:users,email',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed'
    ]);
```

I get this

```
{
"message": "The given data was invalid.",
"errors": {
    "name": [
        "The name field is required."
    ],
    "email": [
        "The email field is required."
    ],
    "password": [
        "The password field is required."
    ]
}
```

But I'm trying to get something like this

```
{
    "message": "The given data was invalid.",
    "errors": {
        "name": "The name field is required.",
        "email": "The email field is required.",
        "password": "The password field is required."
    }
}
```

Comment: What if a field has 2 errors at the same time, like the password field is not confirmed and is shorter than 6 caracters ? that structure is there for a reason.

Comment: On a mobile device they prefer to show only 1 error. So they will fix the first error and then go to the next. This might result in extra requests, but it's important for design purposes.

Comment: You need to overload the method `failedValidation()` in the bastract Request or in your custom FormRequest extention class wich will take you some hours. Or format it in the mobile side and keep the possibility to handle multiple errors in the future and it will take them 5mn.

Comment: here is how to make a formRequest https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#creating-form-requests and declare `failedValidation()` and modify the error bag before throwing the exception. (check method from parent class)

Comment: @GhassanBarghouti Try putting the bail rule on all fields

Answer (score 0):

Laravel errors return an Object of Arrays for each field that just because sometimes the field may have more than an error :

For Example:

Let assume that you have an input set to type Number "`myNumber`" for instance:

Let's assume that we have a validation to the "`myNumber`" ,  let's say :

```
'myNumber' => 'required|numeric|min:6|max:12',
```

If the user didn't enter a value , then Laravel Validate method will return an Message Object containts '`myNumber`' which  is an array of two value the required and the min and max conditions, i think it's clear now, let's go back to your question :

You can easily in your Front-End access the `errors` and instead of having an object of Arrays you could only select the first Index of each Array and bring them together like the following :

```
{
"message": "The given data was invalid.",
"errors": {
    "name": [
        "The name field is required."
    ],
    "email": [
        "The email field is required."
    ],
    "password": [
        "The password field is required."
    ]
}
```

//FORMAT THE ERROR OBJECT JS

```
let FormatedErrors = {

   name = errors.name[0],
   email= errors.email[0],
   password= errors.password[0],
}
```

Now you will easily  get what you want :

```
{
    "message": "The given data was invalid.",
    "errors": {
        "name": "The name field is required.",
        "email": "The email field is required.",
        "password": "The password field is required."
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm working on a restful API. The mobile team is insisting on this format and do not prefer that they handle these things on their end.

Comment: Then you may want to handle it yourself and send the JSON data to your team , just like the answer below , you can do it with PHP instead